# how to link seat reservation project using vb.net with access database

Tags: vb.net

I have a code for seat reservation but i don't know how to link it with access database. I am using buttons as seats so when a seat is selected it hides itself so i want help when the seat is selected the seat number shows in access database .Here is my code :

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim seatnumber As char
    Private Sub BTNA1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNA1.Click
        seatnumber = "A1"
        Confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNA2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNA2.Click
        seatnumber = "A2"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNA3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNA3.Click
        seatnumber = "A3"
        Confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNA4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNA4.Click
        seatnumber = "A4"
        Confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNA5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNA5.Click
        seatnumber = "A5"
        Confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNA6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNA6.Click
        seatnumber = "A6"
        Confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNB7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNB7.Click
        seatnumber = "B7"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNB8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNB8.Click
        seatnumber = "B8"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNB9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNB9.Click
        seatnumber = "B9"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNB10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnb10.Click
        seatnumber = "B10"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNB11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnb11.Click
        seatnumber = "B11"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTNB12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnb12.Click
        seatnumber = "B12"
        confirmseat()
    End Sub

    Public Sub confirmseat()
        Dim intresult As Integer
        intresult = MessageBox.Show("you selected" & seatnumber, "CONFIRM", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If intresult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            seatnumber = "NO"
        Else
            Select Case (seatnumber)
            Case "A1"
                BTNA1.Visible = False
            Case "A2"
                BTNA2.Visible = False
            Case "A3"
                BTNA3.Visible = False
            Case "A4"
                BTNA4.Visible = False
            Case "A5"
                BTNA5.Visible = False
            Case "A6"
                BTNA6.Visible = False
            Case "B7"
                BTNB7.Visible = False
            Case "B8"
                BTNB8.Visible = False
            Case "B9"
                BTNB9.Visible = False
            Case "B10"
                btnb10.Visible = False
            Case "B11"
                btnb11.Visible = False
            Case "B12"
                btnb12.Visible = False
            End Select
            MessageBox.Show("Seat" & seatnumber & "is confirmed", "confirmation")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim seatavailability As Integer
        If seatavailability <> "12" Then
            BTNA1.Visible = True
            BTNA2.Visible = True
            BTNA3.Visible = True
            BTNA4.Visible = True
            BTNA5.Visible = True
            BTNA6.Visible = True
            BTNB7.Visible = True
            BTNB8.Visible = True
            BTNB9.Visible = True
            btnb10.Visible = True
            btnb11.Visible = True
            btnb12.Visible = True

            Dim i As Integer
            Dim reservedseats(1) As Char
            For i = 0 To 12
                Select Case (reservedseats(1))
                    Case "BTNA1"
                        BTNA1.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNA2"
                        BTNA2.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNA3"
                        BTNA3.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNA4"
                        BTNA4.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNA5"
                        BTNA5.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNA6"
                        BTNA6.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNB7"
                        BTNB7.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNB8"
                        BTNB8.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNB9"
                        BTNB9.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNB10"
                        btnb10.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNB11"
                        btnb11.Visible = False
                    Case "BTNB12"
                        btnb12.Visible = False
                End Select
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btncontinue_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncontinue.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: what have you researched and/or tried so far, please? This is not a free write-my-code service, but we will help you with your own attempt to meet your requirement. You do not appear to have even connected your application to the database so far, never mind written code to insert or update values within that database? We don't just provide generic tutorials about this kind of thing. You can google examples of the basics, then we'll fix bugs in problematic code which constitutes an attempt at implementing your feature. P.S.: ask yourself if Access is really the best choice of DBMS.

Comment: I just googles "connect to Access in vb.net" and got 13 million hits. Try a few tutorials and come back with any problems you encounter.

Comment: If your problem is _How do I link my program to Access data?_, for us to help with your problem, we don't need to see all the code which hides/shows buttons or all the code which handles the `Click` event of the buttons.

Comment: Also, are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a LOT of duplicate code. You could simplify your code by writing a single button click handler that forwards the button to `ConfirmSeat`:

```
Private Sub ClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim seatNumber = Mid(DirectCast(sender, Button).Name, 4)
    ConfirmSeat(seatNumber)
End Sub
```

and write `ConfirmSeat` as follows:

```
Private Sub ConfirmSeat(seatNumber As String)
    Dim result As Integer
    result = MessageBox.Show("you selected" & seatnumber, "CONFIRM", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If intresult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        MessageBox.Show("No seat confirmed")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim btn As Button = Controls("btn" & seatNumber)
    btn.Visible = False
    MessageBox.Show($"Seat {seatNumber} is confirmed", "confirmation")
End Sub
```

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do in the `Form1_Load`, as none of the `Select Case` will ever be hit. In any event, the handler could be attached to the `Click` event of the buttons as follows:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
    If Not TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then Continue
    If ctrl Is btnClick Then Continue
    AddHandler DirectCast(ctrl, Button).Click, ClickHandler
Next
```

With that out of the way, we can talk about reading and writing from / to an Access database in your program, using ADO.NET.

---

#### Connections and `Execute*` methods

At the lowest level, you use a connection string:

```
Dim connectionString = 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & 
    "Data Source=" & pathToDatabase
```

to connect to the database with an `OleDbConnection`:

```
Using connection AS New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open

    ' do stuff here

End Using
```

With an open connection, you can execute commands using an `OleDbCommand`. You can use commands together with the `ExecuteNonQuery` method to perform update queries:

```
Dim cmdDeleteAll As New OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM Persons", connection)
cmdDeleteAll.ExecuteNonQuery
```

or together with the `ExecuteScalar` method, to return a single result:

```
Dim cmdCount As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persons", connection)
Dim count As Integer? = cmdCount.ExecuteScalar
```

or using the `ExecuteReader` method, return an `OleDbDataReader`, to iterate once over a set of results -- forward-only.

```
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Persons", connection),
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rdr.Read
        MessageBox.Show($"{rdr["FirstName"]} {rdr["LastName"]}")
    Loop
End Using
```

---

#### Adapters and `DataSet`s

An `OleDbDataReader` has access to one record at a tine, from a single result set. If you want to load the data from multiple result sets, or you need to keep all the data in memory, you can use the `OleDbDataAdapter` to load data into a `DataSet` from an `OleDbConnection` object:

```
Dim ds = new DataSet();
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons"
    Dim adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Persons")
End Using
```

Since a `DataSet` can contain multiple sets of data, there is a hierarchy of objects for working with the `DataSets` and its `DataTables`:

[image: ADO.NET DataSet hierarchy diagram]
(*[Source: ADO.NET Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-architecture)*)

---

#### LINQ against a DataReader

You can also use LINQ and LINQ methods on a data reader, to retrieve a set of objects from a single result set:

```
Dim persons As List(Of Person)
Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    persons = reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
        .Select(Function(row) New Person With {
            .LastName = row["LastName"])
            .FirstName = row["FirstName"]
        }).ToList
End Using
```